# MySQL: how to set the triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

My question here is in this situation:

[image]

I would like to set a trigger so that every time when insert `product_Amount` for same `location_ID` and `product_ID` it can update in the existed row without create a new row.

Comment: please include the table as selectable text, instead of image

Comment: A trigger should not be doing it. This is pure applicative logic and should be implemented in the application itself. Triggers *can* do what you want but you should *not* do it there.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `UNIQUE` constraint on `location_ID, product_ID` and use
`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` in your trigger